# Writing changes to a remote branch with git

Tags: git

I'm quite new to git but I've got my head round the process. Seems to be clone (if it's new), pull, add, commit push... This has worked fine for the most part as the remote repo has a branch called `master` as well (thus git push works without any additional commands).

Now I'm in a situation where the repo I've cloned has multiple branches, e.g:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD
  remotes/origin/example
  remotes/origin/master
```

I'd like to add my changes to the `example` branch and test. If this is successful I'd then like to merge it with the `master` branch.

What commands do I need to run to accomplish these goals?

Comment: Depends on whether you already committed your local changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Jimmy's answer-

1. Switch to the branch you want to work on with `git checkout <branchname>`, like `git checkout example`.
2. Do the work on that branch with `git add`, `git commit -m "enter commit message here"`. Check often with `git status`.
3. Reverse merge master to avoid any merge conflicts: `git merge master`.
4. Do any of the tests you'd like to from this branch.
5. Switch to master: `git checkout master`, and merge into master, `git merge example`.
6. Push the changes to the remote branch: `git push -u example`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any risk of a detached head doing it this way? I've had a message relating to detached head when I've done this in the past. Also can I just put git checkout example? That won't create a local branch called example will it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the commands, was too lazy to help with that

Comment: Detached head - unless you use `rebase`, `reset`, or other destructive commands, there will be no detached head. As for creating a branch called example, I did these commands with example as a fake name. Whatever name of the branch you have, use in place of example.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

1. Switch to `example`
2. Merge `master` so it's up to date (optional)
3. Change stuff and test
4. Commit them
5. Switch to `master`
6. Merge `example` in m`master`
7. Push to `origin` `master`  (optional also `example`)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've asked Briana the same question... When I checkout example is there any specific syntax needed for working on a remote branch? When I've tried this in the past I've just had a local branch with an identical name to the remote branch.

Comment: @user3229731 I would suggest reading a bit more about git to get familiar with remote and local branches. 
There no specific syntax for remotes or locals. Git is complicated for starters. I would suggest a tool like sourcetree for gui. 
A remote banrch can be cloned locally and then syncronized. 
A locally created branch can have a remote branch created for it and by syncronized.

Comment: Yeah it makes a little more sense now :) I think I understand. For some reason I was under the impression you could work directly on a remote branch which obviously isn't possible - what checkout actually does is create a branch with the same name locally and when you push to it, you're actually pushing changes to a branch with the same name remotely... Confusing but logical :D

Comment: @user3229731 yep you got it! May the force be with you now! Welcome to the version control word.

Answer (score 1):

First do git checkout example.
Then do all other commands as you will be on example branch.